# A question of quantitative aptitude based on graph analysis

Tags: algebra-precalculus, contest-math, physics

I am unable to solve this question in quantitative aptitude asked by a junior.

It's image ->

[image]

I thought that temperature will decrease as depth increase as there is no sunlight but that doesn't seems to help.

Answer is B.

> Edit 1: Now posted on Puzzling Stackexchange.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are my two cents, not based on any specialized knowledge.

A. and D. show water at low density under a layer of higher density water.  Surely that low density water is going to rise.

C. shows a sudden shift of temperature at 10 meters. Surely that is unstable.

B. shows a gradual change of temperature with depth.  And the surface is near zero degrees Celsius, so there may be a layer of ice at the top.  I suppose this could be a stable situation.